# CSS Rounded Corner: White lines

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing trouble with some rounded corners on a fixed body container for my page. I extracted the necessary code elements and have places them in JSFiddle. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mAwv2/). You will notice that the borders of the page have white lines on both the inner side and the outer side. Any suggestions on removing them?
Here is my html code:

```
<html><body>
<div id="fixedbody">
    <header>
        <br>
        <br>Header stuff goes here</header>
    <div id="maincontent">Content stuff goes here</div>
    <footer>Footer stuff goes her</footer>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Here is my css code:

```
body {
    background:transparent ;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    background:transparent ;
    min-width: 1200px;
}
#fixedbody {
    width: 980px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-clip: border-box;
}
header {
    height: 515.25px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    width: 980px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    background:transparent ;
}
```

[Here is a picture of the top right corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLyz1.png)

Comment: You have three background properties in your body styles. Try removing a few of those and then follow the advice below...

Comment: your code is very weirdly structured. would consider redo, also should use padding to space out stuff and not br tags x2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the background-color for the parent div "fixedbody":

```
background-color: #ffffff;
```

Since this will result for the bottom part to be transparent, here's how you can fix it so the background color will be white:

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixedbody">
    <header>
        <br/>
        <br/>Header stuff goes here
    </header>
    <div class="whitebg"> <!--Wrap the bottom part with a div tag having a class whitebg-->
        <div id="maincontent">Content stuff goes here</div>
        <footer>Fotter stuff goes her</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for whitebg**

```
.whitebg{
    background-color:white;
    padding:15px;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mAwv2/4/)

Comment: My issue with removing the background color is the the bottom are needs to maintain a white background. However, I believe I can work it out and keep the bottom white without setting the entire container's background. Thank you for such a quick reply.

Comment: usually you don't want to put maincontent inside a div named footer for seo practices

Comment: Thanks for the update. I actually did that to wrap the bottom with a white background. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Some small fixes to the way you use html
also removed all your br tags

**http://jsfiddle.net/mAwv2/5/**

```
body {
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    min-width: 1200px;
}
#fixedbody {
    width: 980px;
    display: block; <-- not needed
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both; <-- not needed since you are not floating anything (float: xxx)
    color: #000000;
    background-clip: border-box;
}
#maincontent, footer { background-color:white; padding:20px; } 

header {
    padding:20px;
    height: 515.25px; <-- try use whole px
    background-color:#0000ff;
    width: 980px;  <-- Not needed, will push content outside of box when applied with padding
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: @RyanSW Check Updated version for some css issue fixes

Comment: When it comes to css, I am literally going to have to rewrite the entire style sheet. I am sure there is a lot to my css that could be made better. The snippet I gave is only part of a much larger file. I am working on redesigning my entire web site. Anyways, thank you for the answer. And I made those changes to my css.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color: #ffffff;
```

Remove this and you should be fine.

Comment: As I mentioned to Amir, the background color for the bottom portion of the container needs to be white. But I can work something out.